# Why does my code skip a step on Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to make an automated test for my company's website. The code **passes my test**, but it **skips a step** while doing it. It is supposed to **First** delete text from the input area and after that add a **new value** to that **same place**.

I have already tried to click the input area and then delete the text with `Delete Text
    Clear Element Text    id=bankAccount.iban`, but it skips this part

This code is from the Robot Framework

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${Username}       myemailaddress@gmail.com
${Password}       12345678
${Browser}        Chrome
${SiteUrl}        http://our.siteaddress.fi/flfuserct-style/login
${DashboardTitle}    Our title was here
${ExpectedWarningMessage}    IBAN is invalid
${WarningMessage}    Adding a new bank failed!
${BankIban}       FI2112345600000788 (((this is not a real IBAN, so don't worry)))
${Delay1}         3s
${Delay2}         1s
${Delay3}         2s
${Delay4}         2s
${Delay5}         3s
${Delay6}         1s


*** Test Cases ***
Login Should Complete Without Errors, But Changing To A New Bank Should Fail Via Invalid IBAN
    Open Page
    Check Title
    Enter User Name
    Enter Password
    Click Login
    sleep    ${Delay1}
    Click My Info
    sleep    ${Delay2}
    Click Bank Account
    sleep    ${Delay3}
    Click Edit
    sleep    ${Delay4}
    Delete Text
    sleep    ${Delay5}
    Enter IBAN
    Assert Warning Message
    sleep    ${Delay6}
    [Teardown]    Close Browser


*** Keywords ***
Open Page
    open browser    ${SiteUrl}    ${Browser}
    Maximize Browser Window

Check Title
    Title Should be    ${DashboardTitle}

Enter User Name
    Input Text    css=[type="text"]    ${Username}

Enter Password
    Input Text    css=[type="password"]    ${Password}

Click Login
    Click Button    css=[type="submit"]

Click My Info
    Click Element    id=my-info

Click Bank Account
    Click Link    css=[href="/flfuserct-style/users/me/bank-accounts/primary"]

Click Edit
    Click Element    css=.MuiButton-label

Delete Text
    Clear Element Text    id=bankAccount.iban

Enter IBAN
    Input Text    id=bankAccount.iban    ${BankIban}

Assert Warning Message
    Element Text Should Be    id=bankAccount.iban-helper-text    ${ExpectedWarningMessage}    ${WarningMessage}
```

---

And this code if from the website

```
<input aria-invalid="true" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input"
id="bankAccount.iban" name="bankAccount.iban" required="" type="text"
value="FI2112345600000788" aria-describedby="bankAccount.iban-helper-text">
```

Code from the robot framework (https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGxvq.jpg)

Code from the log (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jfBB.jpg)

If you can see those pictures (sorry I'm new here) the first one is from the Robot Framework, showing the message log. As you can see it passes the test without errors, but it skips the *Clear Element Text* part.

2nd picture of from the log it says: *Clears the value of the text-input-element identified by the locator.* But that's not happening. It just writes the IBAN after the existing one, and it should delete it.

Also, It seems that I can't do 3 * in a row but Settings, Variables, Test Cases and Keywords have 3 stars

Comment: It does not actually skip the keyword, the log shows that it has been executed.

Comment: Well yes, but actually no. It still doesn't do anything. Do you have any idea that why does it do that?

Comment: There is a clear difference between: "keyword is executed" vs. "keyword does not do what it is supposed to do". Cannot really tell what is the deal as I don't see the outcome or HTML source. Also, try to replace `Sleep`s with `Wait Until Element` keywords to speed up test execution time.

Comment: The outcome and HTML source are about as links in my question. Also when I looked at my code again, I noticed that it really does Skip that part. I have 2 sleeps between them (wait until element is visible doesn't work with me) so I can clearly see it skips this step.

Answer (score 0):

For the `Delete Text` keyword, I think it's a little more clear if you would use something like

```
Input Text id=bankAccount.iban ${EMPTY}
```

That way, you are actually setting the value of the textfield's string to empty string, and you are sure it will work since the same locator and the same method (`Input Text` keyword) surely works on the next step, for adding the actual value (just that instead of adding a value, you're setting this one to Empty String)

Comment: Hey I changed *Clear Element Text    id=bankAccount.iban* to your suggestion, but it still does exactly the same thing than befor... Any ideas?

Comment: Hey I tested this again, on my other code. It seems that ${EMPTY} Doesn't delete my textfield's value, but it adds nothing ' ' to it. Correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Include the below for the `Delete Text` with below code:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    ${element}    timeout=${time}s
Set Focus to Element    ${element}
Click Element    ${element}
Clear Element Text    ${element}
```

Comment: Hey I tried now with your code. Still the same outcome. It does lick the element but doesn't delete it. It also adds the new value to it without problems.